# make matlab variable in workspace as global

Tags: matlab, function, global-variables, global

In the workspace I make a matrix .

[image]

Now I can access the variable in script. Like doing Variable(2) will return 4.

But inside a function like

```
function y= getvariable(x)

y=Variable(x)
end
```

I get error

```
   y=getvariable(2)
    ??? Undefined function or method 'Variable' for input
    arguments of type 'double'.

    Error in ==> getvariable at 3
    y=Variable(x)
```

So how to make the `Variable` matrix global so that I can access it through any function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you *could* use globals

```
>> global Variable = rand(50,12);
```

...

```
function y = getvariable(x)

     % Always needed
     global Variable;

     % Here ya go
     y = Variable;

end
```

the ***MUCH*** better alternative is to use

```
function x = getvariable(x)
     % no body needed    
end
```

which you call as

```
>> y = getvariable(Variable);
```

(Of course, for this contrived example, this would just be equal to

```
>> y = Variable;
```

)

Although there are some legitimate use cases for global variables, in general they tend to  spaghettify your code and make it far more bug-prone and much harder to debug. [Have a read](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) on the subject.

Comment: I have a excel sheet which contain the some 500 different values of variable. So I make a matrix variable from it. And then I use it in a function. And there is no way I think I can input this excel values inside a function. Is there a way _to avoid using global here?_

Comment: @Moz: ...just pass that matrix variable into the function as an argument?

Comment: Why don't you use a function to read your excel file (`xlsread`, or alike) and start from there?

Comment: @Moz: see Nicks comment

Comment: Oh yes, now I understood your _much better alternative_ part..thanks! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As @rody suggested, pass the matrix and the x inside the function

I am just giving an example to make things clear.

**Like you want to access the 10th element of Variable matrix**, so make the function as

```
function y= getvariable(matrixname,no)
y=matrixname(no)
end
```

If you want to access 3rd element of `Variable`, so you type

y=getvariable(Variable,3)

you will get 3rd element

Answer (score 3):

1. call `global Variable` before you define it in your workspace
2. call `global Variable` before you use it in your function

However I suggest you think of other ways to pass variables to your function, as globals might cause difficulties during debugging.

Comment: For more details, see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html